# Saving items when updating a mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to update Divine RPG.  Is it possible to save the items I already have and add them to the new version of the mod?

Comment: they should just be updated along, unless the save system was changed. did you try (back up your `.minecraft` folder and try if it works)

Comment: Welcome to the website. I've researched mod downloading and updating. Maybe this will help: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mods/Installing_Mods#Downloading_Mods

Answer (score 1):

If you just install the mod like you did the first time, it will overwrite the old mod files and update the mod.  As long as you do not load your world without Divine RPG installed, your items will not disappear.